# Hotels on the Las Vegas strip: is there a commitment to gamble?

Tags: las-vegas

I am travelling to Las Vegas for work and want to spend an extra few days there at my own expense.

I am surprised at the cost of hotels on the Las Vegas strip. I suppose that most are subsidised by gamblers spending time in the hotel casino. However, I am not a big gambler and although I will probably gamble something, it would be far below the norm.

In general, is there a commitment to gamble or is it just an expectation that most people will?

Comment: [*The American Physical Society (...) once held its annual meeting in Las Vegas. From the city’s perspective, the meeting was a fiasco. The assembled physicists shunned the usual casino delights: showgirls, blackjack, roulette, craps, and copious amounts of alcohol. (...) Vegas made so little money, legend has it, that the society was asked never to come back. The physicists could do the math: They knew the odds were stacked against them in the casinos. That’s why physicists aren’t the gamblin’ kind*](http://discovermagazine.com/2010/nov/22-one-great-frontier-for-modern-physicists-poker)

Comment: My reason for travelling to Las Vegas is *very* similar - but I have an extra 3 days to have some fun on my own as well.

Comment: APS attendees shunning copious amounts of alcohol? That was not my experience of APS meetings.

Comment: @Calchas Perhaps they were not copious enough by Las Vegas standards

Comment: A (sort of) hidden cost can be the resort fee if applicable.

Comment: I went to a conference in Reno some years ago that was held at Bally's, which at the time advertised itself as having the worlds largest gaming floor. Didn't wager so much as a dime. Nobody cared. So, yeah, gambling is optional.

Comment: *I will probably gamble something, it would be far below the norm* - that's likely what every compulsive gambler said at one point in their life :)

Comment: Hi James; I lived in Vegas for almost 40 years as a dealer and a floorman there. Pay for your room, eat, see the sights and shows, do what you like. No one is watching whether one person or a couple is gambling.

Comment: How could a "commitment to gamble" be made to work in practice?

Comment: There are non-casino hotels as well.

Comment: @gerrit Richard Feynman must have missed that particular convention.

Comment: @CountIblis One possibility I could imagine would be to make the room prices a bit higher and hand the guests a couple of chips when they check in. The chips get marked in a way which means that they are valid for betting but can not be redeemed for real money. When the guests want that money, they need to go to the casino floor and bet them, hoping to at least break even. They don't have to, but they would be stupid not to, because they have nothing to lose. I've never been to Las Vegas, so I don't know if any hotels do that.

Comment: When I lived in Florida, back in the eighties, I would get regular junk mail. If I paid $500, I would get a free flight to Vegas, a free hotel, a portable TV, an entry in a prize draw ***AND*** $500 in chips. I never took them up on it, but always assumed that the chips were marked and would have to played.  I figured that if I played them all on an even money bet at roulette, I would, on average, lose 2/36 of my $500, say $90, making that the total cost of my trip and TV, ***if*** I had iron self-control. Did anyone here ever do that?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I have spent a couple of short vacations in Las Vegas, touring the area during the day, having dinner and people watching in the evening.

I have never encountered a requirement to gamble.

What you will face is an extremely sophisticated system for encouraging gambling, and encouraging losing more money than you intend. You will not get from your room to a restaurant without being exposed to multiple opportunities to gamble. Once in the restaurant, Keno runners will be there in case you want to place a bet. Sit at a bar, and there will be computer poker screens set in the bar top. There are no time cues in casino spaces, so people tend to stay longer than they intend.

Personally, I just don't gamble in Las Vegas. An alternative that works if you do want to gamble is to set aside a definite amount of money you can afford to lose, and stop gambling once that is gone.

Comment: Thinking you'll just stop once your stake is gone is a dangerous idea.  Gambling isn't about how much money you have or don't have.  It's about how it feels.  Up or down you'll keep coming back because of how it feels.  Not everything that feels good is good for you.  The more you like this the less you should be doing it.

Comment: "set aside a definite amount of money you can afford to lose, and stop gambling once that is gone." - It may help to specifically *plan* to lose this money, and think of the process of losing it as entertainment that you are paying for.

Comment: That's precisely what I have done in the past. I figure that I would spend £xx on a normal night out and would have just a much fun at a casino so plan to lose the same amount.

Comment: The people I know who are smart but enjoy gambling think of the stake as money spent for entertainment, and it counts against their spending money for the day, just like paying for dinner or a show.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: That's why you only bring that amount of money, and no ATM cards. :) A more sophisticated version, put that money in your left pocket and put any winnings in the right.

Comment: Not to mention: no possibly place to sit that isn't either a high-priced restaurant or a gambling table or machine.

Comment: I always think of Casinos as modern day arcade games. You put your money in and you play the game. At the end of the game, the money is gone!

Answer (score 21):

There is no obligation to gamble and the audit/reconciliation of guests would be a nightmare if there were.  Gamble as little as you want or nothing at all.

High rollers on "comps" may have different arrangements but these are worked out in advance. As a standard guest you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Yes, this was my experience too: I felt absolutely no pressure to gamble when I stayed at Circus Circus.

Answer (score 18):

I was not in Las Vegas in itself, but in Reno a long time ago which is also a gambling city. Hotels are, as you already indicated, very cheap.

While you have absolutely no obligation to gamble and you will not be even bothered if you are not interested, gambling cities and hotels have a strong commitment that you *should* gamble and increase the recklessness and giddiness of their customers. So I point out what you have to expect.

- Vouchers for free gambling (not much money, only as a bait to start
  gambling).
- Vouchers for free services like drinks and food; if you look out to find
  where it is served, you find that the casino is centralized and you
  cannot avoid looking at it. You are invited to drink alcohol and dance,
  both things which are known that they are "opening up" customers.
- You will be bombarded with what I would call "light and sound shower".
  Blinkenlights and fanfares (I have won). Luxuries (real and imitated) to show that
  money is spent and that giving money does not matter ([Don't be a party pooper or cheapskate](https://s14-eu5.ixquick.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.standbyformindcontrol.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F09%2Fthey-live-2.jpg&sp=89bdbda7daa9a3d03f4d3c2f1e5af50f)).
- Many artists are working in this area, not only magicians like Siegfried & Roy, performing stunts. The reason is not only entertainment, dangerous (real or illusion) situations increases our adrenaline level and makes us prone to reckless decisions.
- The working personnel is looking like freshly gathered from a model show. Interestingly not only women, but also eye candy for the LGBT community. I think I do not need to point out that it does **not** increase rational, intelligent behavior.

Comment: @pnuts hence, the city's marketing catchphrase "What happens in Vegas, stays in Vegas." Where you can see the Eiffel Tower, btw, along with the London Bridge and the canals of Venice.

Comment: The implication that women would not be an attraction to some members of the LGBTQI+ community, or that this community would require human attraction who are not female, is pointless. Either refer to the fact that entertainers are not only female or leave it out completely.

Comment: @Nij I think you did not understand the implication, so I clarify it. There are businesses which rely on female beauty (e.g. "Hooters") and also gender-neutral ones which still strive for the heterosexual beauty ideal. Reno was an exception that I got the impression that the casinos *deliberately* choose **all** charismatic and beautiful humans in the full knowledge that some of them are belonging to the LGBT community. This information is not transferred if I simply say that beautiful men and women are personnel, especially because the LGBT beauty ideals are more diverse.

Comment: Your intent to imply one thing doesn't prevent other implications, one of which was immediately more obvious. You could much more easily have said *staff are employed to appeal to more than just the traditional heteronormative ideal of attractiveness* instead of the contrast you currently do.

Comment: @Nij: I find his current wording better than yours.

Comment: @Nij I absolutely understand that. For example, I realized at once that you excluded the asexuals/agenders from your LBGTQI+ definiton, correctly it should be named (currently) LGBTTTQQIAA. This implies a subconscious bias of LGBT members against asexuals who still inherited this behavior of suppression and denial from the white heterosexual society. I hope you are now aware of that and act accordingly. While I still do not add trigger warnings to my answers and risk that readers are disintegrating, I must inform you that my answer is my personal safe space and criticism hurts my feelings.

Comment: Remember, gentlemen, what happens in a Travel SE comment thread, stays in a Travel SE comment thread.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48499/discussion-on-answer-by-thorsten-s-hotels-on-the-las-vegas-strip-is-there-a-co).

Answer (score 5):

There is no commitment at all to do so, though there will be plenty of cues encouraging you to do it.

Put bluntly, they don't need to chase skeptics like you when they have a steady stream of retirees waiting to deposit their social security checks directly into the nearest machine. They don't need to court you for a few dollars of your money when someone else will willingly give away the entirety of theirs.

Just don't expect anything to work in your favor. One thing to be wary of is hotel personnel approaching you and leading you to think you're entitled to free/discount credits/tickets as a benefit of staying at the hotel, but after some prying it devolves into a commitment to attend timeshare presentations.

Answer (score 3):

Over the years I've spent a few nights in Las Vegas hotels.  There has never been the slightest pressure to gamble, just plenty of incentives.  There used to also be quite a bit of promotional activity directed at locals, over the years I'm up ~$50 on the casinos because of this.  I would accept the match play chips, play until they were gone and walk away.  Gambling doesn't hold the slightest interest to me so they're not going to lure me in.

Since the introduction of the loyalty cards, though, this has almost totally disappeared.  These days all I see are coupon books that offer discounts on the various restaurants etc within the casino.  I don't think I've seen a match play chip in the last decade.